# unable to save file

Tags: php

when I edit a php.ini file  I get this error:

```
[error writing /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini : No such file or directory.
```

Im currently setting up a media server - Ampache.
Thanks for taking time to help with this.
Regards,
TJV.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Because Im setting up the media server in ubuntu. If its not appropriate can you point me to site that can help? Also its an error to do with editing a file in ubuntu.

Comment: Use `sudo` when you edit system files.

Comment: Have been using sudo su.

Comment: make sure the directory exists,

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. Perhaps joining the group of `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini ` wiil help, or read `man sudoedit` or save the file somewhere else (`/tmp`, `$HOME`) and copy it over later.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you sure that PHP 7.4 is installed?

Comment: Many thanks. Ill try these steps out.

Comment: Hi. I went to the website suggested but ,as a newbie to linux, I wasn't sure how to run the script or how to join the group /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini? Also, how do I save the file somewhere else, such as /tmp, or $HOME?

Comment: Hello again! Can someone tell me how to join the group of /etc/php 7.4/apache2/php.ini?  Also my version is Ubuntu server 20.04 .